# Mongoose - Get all elements where id in nested array/Dynamically generated $and clauses

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a small problem.

I want to retrieve all elements in a collection where the id is in a given array. This I can do. The problem is, that the id has to be present in multiple arrays (and I don't know beforehand how many).

So you have

```
Test.find({
  $and: [
      { $in: blabla },
      ...
  ]
```

}

The problem is I can have multiple $in clauses and I do not know how many when I call the function. Is there a way to specifiy this dynamically? (It's just an array of arrays containing id's, if the id is present in each of these arrays, return the element).

Comment: Could you give three examples of documents? Then my answer could be more specific.

Comment: Sure, I"ll post one later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up your `$and` query object programmatically to include all arrays you need:

```
var arrayOfArrays = [[...], [...], ...];
var query = { $and: [] };
for (var i=0; i<arrayOfArrays.length; ++i) {
    query.$and.push({ _id: {$in: arrayOfArrays[i]} });
}
MyModel.find(query, function(err, docs) {...});
```

or you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do it a bit more concisely:

```
var query = { $and: arrayOfArrays.map(function(item) { return {$in: item}; }) };
MyModel.find(query, function(err, docs) {...});
```

Comment: I'm going to test this, but at first glance, this seems like it could and should work for me.

Comment: @KWyckmans: You said `I do not know how many when I call the function`  so how can you build up the query object?

Comment: I can loop over it. If you want I'll post an example of my solution?

Answer (score 1):

The only chance you have is using [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to accomplish this using the aggregation framework and more specifically the $unwind method.

Suppose you have a docs that looks like

```
{
  arrayOfStuff: [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9]
  ]
}
```

Then you could run

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:'$arrayOfStuff'},{$match: {arrayOfStuff: 9}})
```

Comment: But he said that there are mutiple arrays and he does not know which and how many...